# Calling a function in Meteor.method returns undefined

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been trying for the past few days to get a return object from a Meteor method. 
Every time I do this I get `undefined` on the client.

```
Meteor.methods({
 'CORSTest' : function() {
  let url = "www.theverge.com/2017/4/13/15270854/nasa-enceladus-ocean-hydrothermal-vents-alien-life-conditions-cassini-saturn";
   og(url, function(err, meta){
    if(err){
     console.log(err);
     return "Error";
    } else {
     console.log(meta);
     // Returns the correct Object on the server
     return meta;
    }
  })
 },
})
```

I've been going crazy over this. Trying all different variables and syntax and I can't seem to get this to work.

Any help anyone can provide would be incredible.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very common Meteor question. You are calling an asynchronous function inside your method. Your `return` statements are returning values from your anonymous function to the method scope, *not* from the server method to the client. There are several patterns you can follow to get around this. You can use [promises](https://guide.meteor.com/using-npm-packages.html#promises) or you can wrap your anonymous function call and make it synchronous with [Meteor.wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync). For example:

```
Meteor.methods({
  CORSTest() {
    const url = "www.theverge.com/2017/4/13/15270854/nasa-enceladus-ocean-hydrothermal-vents-alien-life-conditions-cassini-saturn";
    const syncFun = Meteor.wrapAsync(og);
    return syncFun(url);
  }
})
```

Comment: Thanks! This has fixed the problem. I'm going to look more into async functions and how they work with Meteor.

Comment: js is full of async functions and consequently so is the Meteor framework. You'll likely want to look at *promises* at some point. Stay out of callback hell!