# MeteorJS: Handling an async function inside another async function?

Tags: javascript, meteor, ecmascript-6

So, I'm lost on how to handle this properly.

What I want to do is:

```
// client side
Meteor.call("getData", url, function(images) {
  console.log(images); // get array of image src
});

// server side
Meteor.methods({
  "getData": (url) => {
      var images = [];
     // here is where I am lost
     // scrape the images
     scrape.request(url, function(err, $) {
       if (!err) {
          $('img').each(function(img) {
            let src = img.attribs.src;
            images.push(src);
          }
          // so at this point, I can console log an array on the server, but I need to bring it back to the client
       }
     } // now, how do I push all these and then signal to return the array?
   return images; // returns undefined, not waiting for all the data
   // I'm not sure how to wait for the array to be updated.
}});
```

Thoughts?

So, recap, I want to get an array back of all the image sources scraped from the website passed to the Meteor method.

Comment: Essentially a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404612/calling-a-function-in-meteor-method-returns-undefined/43404925#43404925

Comment: @MichelFloyd If only! The problem is, the example you point to is essentially just returning a value from the callback of an async function. My example is not this straightforward because I am calling an async function from the client to the server, the server then makes an async call to a website and returns data AND then separates the data I need AND then I want to return the separated data. If you think otherwise, put your money where your code is and show me the answer :)!

Comment: What about using `Promise`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good [tutorial](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/synchronous-methods) on [Meteor.wrapAsync](https://docs.meteor.com/api/core.html#Meteor-wrapAsync) that lays this out. Also [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26226668/2805154) provides more details and explains error handling.

All the action happens on the server. In your case:

```
Meteor.methods({
  getData(url) => {
    const syncScrape = Meteor.wrapAsync(scrape.request);
    try {
      const $ = syncScrape(url,{});
      let images = [];
      $('img').each(img => {
        images.push(img.attribs.src);
      });
      return images;
    }
    catch(error) {
      throw new Meteor.error(error);
    }
  }
});
```

Also your client call needs to include an error from the callback:

```
Meteor.call("getData", url, (error, images) => {
  if (!error) console.log(images); // get array of image src
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the end, I couldn't get it working so I switched my scrapper to [scraperjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scraperjs) and used this answer to make that one work. Also, thanks for putting up with my sass! I was very tired and frustrated at that point.

Comment: Glad you got it working. My Canadian spouse encourages me to help her compatriots ;)