# Javascript: trouble getting return data from api call

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am a little stuck trying to get a token from the server code to the client. In my server code my call works and a token is returned as `var clientToken`. The problem is that when I return the response I am getting undefined on my client side.

I am thinking it is because the return token is happening before the response is returned but I am having trouble fixing it. 
server code:

```
'client.token.braintree'(submission){

  var token = gateway.clientToken.generate({}, function (err, response) {
     var clientToken = response.clientToken
     console.log("token", clientToken);
      return clientToken
   });
     return token

 },
```

client code:

```
 Meteor.call('client.token.braintree', {customer_id:
   this.props.customer_id}, (err,res) => {
     if(!err) {
       console.log("tokens client side", res)
      }

 });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a function in Meteor.method returns undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404612/calling-a-function-in-meteor-method-returns-undefined)

Comment: This question is asked all the time. Here is one of them https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43404612/calling-a-function-in-meteor-method-returns-undefined